# Oracle:How to determine the size of available shared memory of operating system while setting MEMORY_TARGET parameter for oracle instance?

Tags: oracle

According to the oracle document:"The size of the shared memory should be at least the greater of MEMORY_MAX_TARGET and MEMORY_TARGET for each Oracle instance on the computer."Oracle document also suggest that we can use the command **`df –k /dev/shm`** to get the available shared memory.
I got a little confuse of of **shared memory** while I am reading the definition of the shmall parameter: **This parameter sets the total amount of shared memory pages that can be used system wide , it means that the total amount of shared memory available on the system equals to (shmall*PAGE_SIZE)**
So when I am going to set the value of  MEMORY_TARGET, which should I go for, **shmall*PAGE_SIZE** or  **`df –k /dev/shm`**

Answer (score 1):

You should go for the solution that fulfills your requirements.

Both `shmall` and `/dev/shm` are configurable, so first you should to configure them, and after that, you can set `MEMORY_TARGET`. The default value (on Oracle Linux 7) of `shmall` is 4 TB, which is irrelevant for most systems. The default size of `/dev/shm` is 50% of the physical memory.

If you use the default settings, following `/dev/shm` for sizing can be a viable option, but it may be suboptimal ("Unused memory is wasted memory").

To make things more complicated, `MEMORY_TARGET` includes PGA, which is not shared memory.

Also, my personal opinion/practice: whenever I can, I use ASMM (sga_target/sga_max_size + pga_aggreate_target) instead of AMM (memory_target/memory_max_size). Especially since hugepages works with ASMM, but not with AMM.